# Oracle parallel hint on cluster

Tags: oracle, parallelism

I wanted to use the parallel hint that would give the best performance in my query which is a equi-join query where the two tables are in a cluster and the join column is a cluster index. I wasn't sure if I should use the parallel option on one of the tables `PARALLEL(table1, 4)`, both of the tables `PARALLEL(4)` or on the clusters index `PARALLEL_INDEX(index_name, 4)`? Here was my query:

```
SELECT /*+ USE_HASH(a, b)  */ a.NAME
    ,b.price
    ,
FROM Customer a
    ,Sales b
WHERE b.Cust_id < 2000
    AND b.Cust_id = a.Cust_id;
```

Here is the execution plan for this query:

[image]